# Polar capacitor orientation in Circuitikz seems wrong?

Tags: circuitikz

In general, polar capacitors seem to be drawn with the curved end as the negative pole:
[image: textbook]

However, doing this (naively) in `circuitikz` seems to result in a "reversed" version:

```latex
\draw (0, 0) [pC] ++(1, 0);
```

[image: mwe]

This can be fixed by adding the `invert` key to the drawing command:

```latex
\draw (0, 0) [pC, invert] ++(1, 0);
```

[image: circuitikz correctly polarized capacitor]

Still, is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I just noticed that `ecapacitor` and `polar capacitor` seem to have opposite directions. Strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is arguably wrong, but it's documented:

[image: manual excerpt for 0.9.4]

And it's like this since at least 0.6:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz-0.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american
    ]
    \draw (0,0) to[ecapacitor] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,-2) to[polar capacitor] ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

so I am quite afraid of changing it --- it's difficult to spot in a big circuit and can give nasty surprises.

I could try to consider it for the `1.0` release, maybe; --- also with the other thing that I do not like a lot, the fact that `invert` does not change voltage directions. But I don't know, I like the principle of least surprise...

#### update:

in the next version of `circuitikz`, 0.9.5, there will be a new component, `curved capacitor`:

[image: new component description]

[image: deprecated old component]

Yep, I know, it's "its polarity", no "it's polarity"... Can I blame the automatic corrector?

Comment: Arguably, for a new user, the least surprise occurs when the polar capacitor matches convention :)...would be great to see this in 1.0!

Comment: @AnshulSinghvi the best thing is to define a new bipoles `cC`, `curved capacitor` or whatever which has the correct orientation, and remove the old one from the manual (or just commenting it) so that old circuits are not affected. I will try to do that as soon as I can.